# How to pass vuejs html template as slot and access from data or method

Tags: html, templates, vue.js

I have a component like this:

```html
<my-dropzone value:"...."> 
    <h1>upload</h1>
    <p>your files</p>
</my-dropzone>
```

and my vuejs component is:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="dropzone"></div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  ....

    export default {
        props:{
           ....
        },
        components: {
            vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
        },
        data() {
            return {
                arrayFiles: [],
                dropzoneOptions: {

                   ....
                    dictDefaultMessage: // <------ I want to assign slot data here
                    ,
                  ....
        },
        mounted() {
           .....

        },
        methods: {
            .....
        },
        computed: {
           .....
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to get slot html data and assign to some local variable of component and also use in method. Is it possible? Is there any better solution to pass html to data variable

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vue.js `vm.$slots` to access the slot children as HTML nodes. It is the only recommended way. [Official Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots) docs really explain it well.

You can use `render()` function for your components instead of `template`. Slots are designed to be used effectively with a render function. Without render function, using `vm.$slots` is not really that useful.

#### Long explanation:

Vue **slots** are not designed to work the way you need. Imagine slots as a rendering area. Also, a slot doesn't really contain HTML as a string. It is already passed from virtual-dom and rendered as `HTMLElements` on screen. By the time code is processed, `html` as a string has transformed into a render function.

Alternately, If you need to really access the underlying HTML nodes, then consider using plain DOM API like `querySelector()`, etc. As far as the `$refs` is concerned, Content within the slot is owned by the parent component and thus you cannot use it.